# Wireless not working on an HP 4410s?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, internet

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04, my WIFI stopped working. I have tried many fixes but nothing works. When I click on Install additional drivers, no drivers show up saying **"No proprietary drivers are in use on this system"** 
Wired connection works but wireless doesn't work and no drivers detected.

```
sudo lspci -nn 

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub [8086:2a40] (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2a42] (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2a43] (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2937] (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 [8086:2938] (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 [8086:2939] (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 [8086:293c] (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:293e] (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 [8086:2940] (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 [8086:2944] (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 [8086:2948] (rev 03)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 [8086:294a] (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:2934] (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:2935] (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:2936] (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 [8086:293a] (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller [8086:2919] (rev 03)
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 2 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] [8086:2928] (rev 03)
00:1f.5 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 2 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] [8086:292d] (rev 03)
84:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8072 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller [11ab:436c] (rev 10)

sudo lshw -class network

*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 88E8072 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:84:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 10
   serial: 00:25:b3:5a:95:a7
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:44 memory:d0600000-d0603fff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d8900000-d891ffff

rfkill list all

0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Any idea what kind of wireless card is in there? that's the information we need.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

Can you double check to make sure your wireless has not been disable in BIOS, looks like only your Ethernet card and not wireless. This laptop should use a Broadcom 43xx wireless card, if wireless is enable, try the following

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

and reboot.